# Do any sources discuss reading Megillas Ester too fast?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, torah-reading, megillat-esther, shiurim-measurements

I remember seeing a source explaining that ideally Megilla should be read somewhat fast because it is called "iggeret" (a letter), and letters are read at fast speed out loud. I've also heard the viewpoint supporting slow reading to facilitate listeners' following and understanding.

Do any halachik sources discuss speed limit for reading Megillas Ester?
For example, if the reader is able to pronounce words clearly at a very fast rate of speed (say 12 minutes for the entire megilla), would the speed that's too fast for most people to follow invalidate the Megilla reading?

Comment: Nice Q. FWIW, I think I remember an Israeli who could do that just fine. 12 minutes sounds doable.

Comment: I've found nothing in any halachic source that puts any time limit or rate to any part of any ritual service - be it davening, Torah reading, Amidah or anything else. The only thing it says regarding Megillah reading is that everyone must hear every word. Of course, implied in the ruling is that the reader actually pronounces each word and isn't mumbling, muffling or skipping even one word. As long as he's done that, he can go as fast as the Shamash allows him to. (I say the "Shamash" but it could be any person who has appointed him to perform the job.)

Comment: in your question….      you don’t say if he had a minyan of people that heard every word